# How do I call another script with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a list of scripts that I would like to run consecutively.  How do I go about this?

I have generally used

```
from subprocess import call
call(["python","C:\\11.py"])
```

But am wanting to do it in pytest.

A.py

```
print('h')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  test_add()
```

Test_add.py

```
print('k')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  test_add2()
```

test_add2.py

```
print('done')
```

Comment: What have you tried....The documentation for pytest is very clear. Also It would help if you added your directory structure. Do you `__init__.py` to make your collection a package?

Comment: *The documentation for pytest is very clear.* Just a tip: never assume this. I help coworkers parse the pytest docs on a regular basis. If you're not already intimately familiar with unit testing and the associated jargon, the docs can be pretty abstract. A better question to ask would be: "what parts of the documentation are you having trouble understanding?"

Answer (score 0):

If you have a python package using `__init__.py` see [These docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html) for more detail.

In the most basic case you have two files. Your module, and the pytest module. These can be put in the same folder, say **ProjectA**.

```
ProjectA/
    a.py
    test_a.py
```

**a.py**

```
def some_code():
    print('code to be tested')
```

**test_a.py**

```
import a

def test_some_code():
    a.some_code()
```

Then to run the code:

```
$ cd path/to/ProjectA
$ pytest
```